# Search and replace serialised text in a column in mysql (without unserialising?)

Tags: search, serialization, replace, deserialization

I am trying to search and replace a specific text in a column in `mssql` based on specific search criteria. I am simply getting it wrong.

I have tried to use the 2 examples from this thread but cant get it right - [Updating serialised array in mysql (without unserialising?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277736/updating-serialised-array-in-mysql-without-unserialising)

***note `wp_postmeta` is the table name and `meta_value` is the column name***

```
SET @search = 'View Map +';
SET @replace = 'View New Map2 +';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=REPLACE(meta_value, CONCAT('s:', 
LENGTH(@search), ':"', @search, '"'), CONCAT('s:', LENGTH(@replace), ':"', 
@replace, '"')) WHERE `meta_id` = 170442
```

**I am getting this error**

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)
```

**I have also tried this second option but it still fails**

```
$old = 'View Map +';
$new = 'View New Map2 +';

$search = 's:' . strlen($old) .':"' . $old . '"';
$replace = 's:' . strlen($new) .':"' . $new . '"';

$query = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=REPLACE(meta_value, 
'{$search}','{$replace}') WHERE `meta_id` = 170442 and 
meta_value LIKE '%View Map +%';";
```

I am getting this error

```
$old = 'View Map +';
```

MySQL said:

```
Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$old = 
'View Map +''at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head over this but the above option 1 works fine now.. I did not have the whole array in the search and replace box but part of it thus the error